# Debug queries as they are executed by pgbench

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking, query-performance

I'm seeing a strange output from `pgbench`, and I don't know what other tools there are to try to understand the reasons for disproportionately big latencies.

Here are the results of `explain` run against the populated `pgbench` database:

```
pgbench=# explain analyze UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + 12345 WHERE tid = 100;
                                                   QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on pgbench_tellers  (cost=0.00..2.25 rows=1 width=358) (actual time=0.077..0.077 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on pgbench_tellers  (cost=0.00..2.25 rows=1 width=358) (actual time=0.023..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (tid = 100)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 99
 Total runtime: 0.092 ms
(5 rows)

pgbench=# explain analyze UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + 12345 WHERE bid = 10;
                                                    QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on pgbench_branches  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=1 width=370) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on pgbench_branches  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=1 width=370) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (bid = 10)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 9
 Total runtime: 0.060 ms
(5 rows)
```

So, according to the planner, both queries should be in the same ballpark, with the second query being, perhaps, slightly faster due to fewer rows it has to scan.

The reality is, however this:

```
  tps = 695.349735 (including connections establishing)
  tps = 695.355481 (excluding connections establishing)
  statement latencies in milliseconds:
          0.002471        \set nbranches 1 * :scale
          0.000743        \set ntellers 10 * :scale
          0.000684        \set naccounts 100000 * :scale
          0.000786        \setrandom aid 1 :naccounts
          0.000585        \setrandom bid 1 :nbranches
          0.000609        \setrandom tid 1 :ntellers
          0.000583        \setrandom delta -5000 5000
          0.124286        BEGIN;
          0.225984        UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + :delta WHERE aid = :aid;
          0.167551        SELECT abalance FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE aid = :aid;
          0.570490        UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + :delta WHERE tid = :tid;
          3.230071        UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + :delta WHERE bid = :bid;
          0.134970        INSERT INTO pgbench_history (tid, bid, aid, delta, mtime) VALUES (:tid, :bid, :aid, :delta, CU
  RRENT_TIMESTAMP);                                                                                                    
          7.037875        END;
```

In other words, the query that was believed to complete about 30% faster in reality completed 5000% slower.

---

My guess, so far, is that PostgreSQL planner has defaults that are appropriate for low-latency storage, however, these tests are performed against an iSCSI device with, potentially much higher latency (but also high queue depth and high bandwidth).

So, I would like to find out if there's a way to produce a more detailed report on what I/O operations PostgreSQL performed during the test (from its perspective, I can see the iSCSI portal side).  And, if possible, a way to configure the planner to adjust its estimates for the "typical cloud" situation, where latencies are high, but so are queue depths and bandwidth.

---

After enabling `auto_explain` as well as few other logging configuration changes, below is the relevant output:

```
LOG:  duration: 2667.835 ms  plan:
        Query Text: UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + 3781 WHERE bid = 9;
        Update on pgbench_branches  (cost=4.26..8.27 rows=1 width=370) (actual time=2667.834..2667.834 rows=0 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=11
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pgbench_branches  (cost=4.26..8.27 rows=1 width=370) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                Recheck Cond: (bid = 9)
                Buffers: shared hit=3
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pgbench_branches_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: (bid = 9)
                      Buffers: shared hit=2

LOG:  duration: 9.604 ms  plan:
        Query Text: UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + 3845 WHERE tid = 33;
        Update on pgbench_tellers  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=358) (actual time=9.604..9.604 rows=0 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=7
          ->  Index Scan using pgbench_tellers_pkey on pgbench_tellers  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=358) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tid = 33)
                Buffers: shared hit=3
```

So, the difference seems to be in `Bitmap Heap Scan` + `Bitmap Index Scan` vs `Index Scan`. I'm still unsure as to why it's different and what it means in terms of I/O.

---

## Update 2

From more reading about kinds of scans and the rationale behind using them, it seems that PostgreSQL chooses to use `Index Scan` for bigger table, because it believes that most results will be irrelevant to the query, while it uses `Bitmap Heap Scan` because it believes that the result set will be small enough that it's easier to scan "everything" and then filter out unnecessary result (of which there won't be too many). However, due to the huge latency impact, the heap scan turns out to be the wrong strategy.

---

## Update 3

My previous interpretation was wrong. Or, at least, not the full answer. After adding I/O time reporting and lock time reporting, it appears that the time PostgreSQL waits to acquire locks is responsible for the delays. Now, the bigger question is why the contention on the larger table is so much higher, or is there some other mechanism at play that makes these locks so terribly slow (sometimes > 3 seconds).

Comment: Enable auto_explain and log the execution plans of everything above 3 milliseconds.

Comment: Is this repeatable or a one-time thing?

Comment: @jjanes yes, this is repeatable with amazing accuracy (up to two decimal digits).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated my question with the details from the `auto_explain` log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running something else besides pgbench on the database, nothing would lock you for two seconds.

Also, the bitmap heap scan is not at fault (it is fast), it is the update itself.

The most likely cause is I/O overload – check the I/O wait time spent by the CPU.

Another (unlikely) possibility, perhaps in combination with the previous one, would be a tiny `shared_buffers`, so that the backend cannot find a clean buffer.

Comment: Nothing is running on this VM, only the test, but, as I mentioned earlier, the I/O latency is high (since it's attached over network). I see from the log that locks can be held for 4 seconds at least (maybe even more, depending on contention level). I can definitely see from the aggregate statistics that some queries, depending on contention, can have either ~10 or less milliseconds latency, or 10 *seconds* or higher latency.

Comment: I/O wait is high, but not absurdly high. You'd expect high I/O wait from an application doing synchronous I/O anyways, so, that doesn't really bother me (I/O wait fluctuates between 20% and 40%, can differ based on contention). I'll try increasing `shared_buffers` and report back.

Comment: 20% to 40% I/O wait is crazy high, so that is your problem. Reduce the I/O latency or suffer.

Comment: It's really not... if you have # of threads >> # CPU cores and >> queue depths, that's expected. From what I understand, PostgreSQL can only do blocking I/O (no libaio nor POSIX async I/O, certainly not uring I/O), so, that's fine. I can get much lower I/O wait times by running fewer clients, but it won't increase the performance of the database.

Comment: Whoa, increasing `shared_buffers` to the suggested value (1/4 of RAM) had a *huge* effect. Essentially, it increased `pgbench` performance by 100%. The contention has almost disappeared.

Comment: That's because of the I/O reduction.

Comment: Well, of course. However, now this brings me to questioning of how should the results of this test be presented to anyone / how would anyone drive any conclusions from them... I mean, TCP-B, the concept, this test is trying to implement, is meant to be generic / independent of hardware / DB specifics. It's just meant to say "this system is X good". But, now I've discovered that this test can be "gamed" to give results anywhere from X to almost X*10... It's very unfortunate that caching plays such a tremendous role in determining the performance of the system :(

Comment: That's pretty much an open-ended question. When running a benchmark, the result says "this benchmark performs such-and-such". Any interpretation beyond that is fragile. In particular, it says nothing about your projected workload. Essentially, you showed that you can drive the system into I/O overload (believe it or not), and it gives you an idea of how much I/O you can do in such a situation.